# Windows phone 8: open facebook specific post in app from code

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, deep-linking

I'm implementing a Facebook app in Windows phone 8, and I would like to use deep-link with Facebook app to handle the content of post, it could be more user friendly I think.

Anyone can tell how to go to specific post in Facebook app just like below permalink?

https://www.facebook.com/Engadget/posts/10152561525522370

If I have post id '10152561525522370', how to launch Facebook app and go to that specific post? Is it something like below?

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:XXXX?id=POST_ID"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Am sure there is one. but found no documentation. Because in wp8.1 Me Tile -> what's new -> click any post and that post opens in facebook app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an undocumented way to achieve this.

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:specificpost?id=POST_ID"));
```

But it seemed that some post_id  doesn't work.

Comment: Any link you learned this from? I want to post a link to Facebook. I found how to post a text using `fb:post?text=foo` but how can I post a link?